# User Auth - oAuth questions

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, oauth, passport.js

I have in the past done a hand rolled app that stores a user token on client side $window.sessionStorage.

I have since then realized this is not safe. I am now looking for the most safe, standard way to secure an app that uses a node/express backend api that I will make, and also uses a front end that makes requests to this api such as angular for web or a native mobile app. Plus, whenever I would close the browser, I would have to re-log in because the $window's session storage was wiped out.

From what I've researched thus far, one of the safest ways to date if you're going to handroll it is to store a jwt in an http only secure cookie.

However, I'd kind of like to use a service that already exists, such as oAuth. Couple questions:

---

1) How safe is oAuth in terms of keeping ownershp of your userbase? What if 3 years from now oAuth just suddenly or slowly dies out? Aren't all my users technically stored on their server? How would I keep my users native to my app?

2) If I'm going to be creating a startup app in the same realm as snapchat, twitter, tumblr, etc... would it be generally recommended to use a service like oAuth to handle my authentication? Of course the future is unknown, but assuming the best, that my app would reach millions of users, would using a service like oAuth still be a smart choice? It seems like once you start using oAuth, there's never any going back to storing your users in your own database a year or two down the road.

Thanks

Comment: Recommendations are *explicitly* off-topic on SO.

Comment: Recommendations about what?

Comment: Everything, authentication protocols and services included.

Comment: Okay I'll just change the language around thanks

Comment: That seems unlikely to fix it. Maybe learn [ask].

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is an open standard for authorization.

Maybe you're thinking about Auth0. There are a lot of services that can handle user authorization for you, including Auth0, Stormpath, Apigee, UserApp, AuthRocket or Amazon Cognito. Whichever you choose, make sure that you can get the database from them in case you want to stop using their service. Not everyone explicitly offers an easy way to leave them but if that's important for you then make sure who suits your needs and who doesn't, and base your decision on that.

As for OAuth, see the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth article.
There's a huge [list of OAuth providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OAuth_providers) on Wikipedia but those are services like Twitter, Google or Facebook. In a way you can use one of those services to manage all your logins but as soon as they see you as their competition, you're in trouble. I've heard stories like that.

Some interesting read on the subject:

- [The dangers of OAuth/Social Login](https://mortoray.com/2014/02/21/the-dangers-of-oauthsocial-login/)
- [Signing Me onto Your Accounts through Facebook and Google: a Traffic-Guided Security Study of Commercially Deployed Single-Sign-On Web Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/signing-me-onto-your-accounts-through-facebook-and-google-a-traffic-guided-security-study-of-commercially-deployed-single-sign-on-web-services/)
- [OpenID Vulnerability report: Data confusion](http://openid.net/2012/03/14/vulnerability-report-data-confusion/)
- [Social Login Setups – The Good, the Bad and the Ugly](https://cloudrail.com/social-login-setups-good-bad-ugly/)

Comment: RSP... Thanks for the response. Does OAuth handle jwt for you? I basically just want to set up my users model so that when they login with the correct credentials, jwt is set to go and even if a user closer the browser, they are still authorized until they explicitly sign out. Thanks.

Comment: @Tyler OAuth doesn't handle JWT. JWT is JSON Web Token described in RFC 7519 which is the work of the OAuth working group. Some authentication providers explicitly support JWT, like e.g. Auth0 - see https://auth0.com/docs/jwt - Some providers don't support it themselves and you have to roll your own solution, like e.g. with Apigee even though it does use OAuth - see https://community.apigee.com/questions/9860/support-for-jwt-token.html - You have to look around which of the services that I wrote about (and I'm sure there are more) support JWT out of the box and which don't.

Comment: Will research all the services you wrote about, thanks. How about PassportJS? I didn't see that mentioned, but I'm starting to steer away from oAuth, in this specific case, because of those articles I skimmed that you provided.

Comment: @Tyler Passport can do much more than just OAuth. E.g. see https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local for a local authentication strategy - there's an example on how to authenticate users against your own Mongo database.